# How to create custom route to a page on a subdomain in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, routes, subdomain

I want to set a new Route in WordPress that will be redirected to the desired path by entering a specific pattern.

for example: When I enter any url like below:

```
http://audio.mywebsite.com/Everything
http://audio.mywebsite.com/**********
http://audio.mywebsite.com/0123456789
```

These routes and similar ones redirects to sound.php

```
http://audio.mywebsite.com/wp-content/sounds/sound.php
```

### I have already used this code for the below redirect

```
http://mywebsite.com/audio/Everything  -->  http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/sounds/sound.php

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^audio/([^/]*)/?','wp-content/sounds/sound.php','top');
}
```

---

I have already used this code for the below redirect.
The custom_rewrite_rule() function works fine for the redirect, but I can't change it for the subdomain.

In fact, I want to instead

```
http://mywebsite.com/audio/Everything
```

I have the following URL

```
http://audio.mywebsite.com/Everything
```

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess:

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^audio\.mywebsite\.com\/([^.]+)\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://audio.mywebsite.com/wp-content/sounds/sound.php [R=301,L]
...
```

or, if your site is already in `audio.mywebsite.com`, put this in your theme function.php:

```php
add_action( 'init' , 'my_redirect' );
function my_redirect() {
  if (preg_match( '\/([^.]+)$' , $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] ) {
    wp_redirect('/wp-content/sounds/sound.php');
  }
}
```

(code is untested, please recheck the regular-expression)

Comment: The above codes do not work. "wp_redirect" got an error. Can you write a code similar to the following code?               add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule_image', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule_image() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^image/([^/]*)/?','wp-content/themes/jannah/_single-files/image.php','top');
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).